# Create a MS Planner Checklist from Flow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, flow, microsoft-flow

Considering I need the following Microsoft Planner Task to be created:

[image: My MS Planner Task]

How can I create this in Sharepoint Flow? I have looked at the *Update Task Details* parameters to try to do this, but I don't see how this can be done. Is there documentation on the detailed input array that will create a Checklist as I have above?

> Todd's Work
>
> Cole's Work

I don't see here where that can be done:

[image: Flow update task]

Comment: There is a `switch to input entire array` button to the left of the references. But I am under the assumption that is just for inputting additional references in json type format. I don't think it has anything to do with checklists, which is what I'm looking for. Am I under the correct assumption?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?